# Vite is only compiling one scss file in laravel

Tags: laravel, sass, vite

I'm having a strange issue. I have multiple SCSS and Js files for each page in my laravel v10.3

It not compiling all the SCSS files . It only compiles and generates the first file from input array.

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
         //   input,
            input: [
               'resources/css/app.css',
               'resources/js/app.js',
               'resources/sass/dashboard/pages/student/profile.scss',
               'resources/sass/dashboard/pages/student/eligibility.scss',
               'resources/sass/dashboard/pages/student/dashboard.scss',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

you can see after app.js i have ( profile , eligibility , dashboard ) scss files.
After build command it only generates the first one ( profile )

This is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChCTu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewHnx.png)

And if i will remove the profile , It will only generate ( eligibility ) scss file.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening ? Whereas it does not make issues in JS files.